# Kubernetes Ingress url-based routing on same host with rewrite

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have encountered a weird behavior in nginx-ingress on k8s.
I have a domain example.com, I want to route all requests to the frontend service and all requests with /api to the backend service and when redirecting to the backend the nginx ingress must rewrite the request and remove the /api prefix for example:
example.com/api/user/1 shoud be rewritten to /user/1
and example.com/home should be routed to the frontend server and retrieve the home page.

Below the manifest file.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"  # Enable automatic redirection to HTTPS

    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2  # Rewrite /api to / for backend service

spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - '*.example.com'
      secretName: cert-tls
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: "example.com"
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/"
            backend:
              service:
                name:landing
                port:
                  number: 3000 #map to service port
          - pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            path: /api(/|$)(.*)
            backend:
              service:
                name: backend
                port:
                  number: 3001 
          
    - host: "dashboard.example.com"
```

**The current behavior is:** routing to the backend works perfectly with the rewrite however the frontnend is not working it says too ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. Removing the rewrite target annotation will make the frontend work and the backend wont work.

Is there a way to fix this or should I create multiple ingress files ?